# Facing issue in custom connector : mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, connector, mule-component

I create custom connector in mule esb using Anypoint connector project.
I used REST type API. Following is my code

```
@Processor
    @ReconnectOn(exceptions = { Exception.class })
    @RestCall(uri="http://myapi/{content}", method=HttpMethod.GET)
    public abstract void myProcessor(@RestUriParam("content") String content) throws IOException;  


    public ConnectorConnectionStrategy getConnectionStrategy() {
        return connectionStrategy;
    }

    public void setConnectionStrategy(ConnectorConnectionStrategy connectionStrategy) {
        this.connectionStrategy = connectionStrategy;
    }
```

I used my custom connector as follow..

```
<connect-custom:config-type name="customConnector" doc:name="customConnector" />

 <flow name="testinghelloFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <connect-custom:my-processor config-ref="customConnector" content="APP" doc:name="customConnector"/>

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

I got following error..

```
ERROR 2015-02-16 19:06:13,418 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1031) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633) ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.6.0.jar:?]
INFO  2015-02-16 19:06:13,624 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'testinghello' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2015-02-16 19:06:13,812 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer:
```

When I test my class using junittest then got following error..

```
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'Connect__Configuration_type_strategy': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.mule.modules.customconnect.adapters.ConnectorConnectionStrategyBasicAdapter]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.tck.junit4.AbstractMuleContextTestCase.createMuleContext(AbstractMuleContextTestCase.java:236)
    at org.mule.tck.junit4.AbstractMuleContextTestCase.setUpMuleContext(AbstractMuleContextTestCase.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$StatementThread.run(FailOnTimeout.java:62)
```

How can I solve this error??
I got this error at compile time.. I just tried to fetch data using REST Api..
Which step i am missing???
How is it possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an issue with the latest devkit version. Can you try using the previous version and check whether this solves your issue? HTH.

Answer (score 1):

As @clare mentioned, this appears to be an issue with the 3.6 DevKit in Anypoint Studio.  This issue occurs if you generate the class and tests in Anypoint Studio 3.6.

You can get the connector to work correctly if you remove all the methods and variables in the connector class that are related to Connection Strategy, including the @ConnectionStrategy annotation and ConnectorConnectionStrategy class.  You then have to update the connector config type in the XML config file from `<connector:config-type>` to `<connector:config>`, (where "connector" is your connector name).  This is the previous style.

Basically, go back to the 3.5.x way of doing the connector and you will be fine.  I'm sure an update will come out soon for this.